# Why is Pivot not responding to touch when inside a row details section of UWP datagrid

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, combobox, pivot

I am developing a UWP app where my requirement is- I have a Datagrid with row details section defined using a DataTemplate resource. And inside the template there will be a pivot with multiple pivot items. One of the pivot items will have a combobox.

```
<Page>
    <Page.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="RowDetailsTemplate">
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="50,0,30,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Yellow">
                <Pivot Tapped="Pivot_Tapped">
                    <PivotItem Header="ABC">
                        <ComboBox Header="Colors" PlaceholderText="Pick a color" Width="200" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                            <x:String>Blue</x:String>
                            <x:String>Green</x:String>
                            <x:String>Red</x:String>
                            <x:String>Yellow</x:String>
                        </ComboBox>
                    </PivotItem>
                    <PivotItem Header="DEF">            
                    </PivotItem>
                </Pivot>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Page.Resources>
    
    <controls:DataGrid RowDetailsTemplate="{StaticResource RowDetailsTemplate}" />
</Page>
```

**The problem or the issue is- Neither the pivot items nor the combobox work on touch. Obviously i have touch screen and these all work when outside a rowdetails template absolutely fine. Why not in row details template?**

**And another observation- as soon as I remove all the pivot items except the one that contains the combobox, the combobox starts responding to touch just fine even inside the row details template.**

Comment: Have you checked my reply about your question?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to start somewhere; and that would be to add event handlers to the Combobox if you expect "interactions"; e.g. SelectionChanged. I think you're expecting "Tapped" to be inherited; but it isn't.

At the very least, "selectors" within other selectors, starts introducing side effects that "confuses" the selection / click / tapped / pointer pressed / drag processes.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the same behavior with touch. It is recommended that you use [Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.hub?view=winrt-22621) to replace `Pivot`. My test code is as follows.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="RowDetailsTemplate">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="50,0,30,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Yellow">
            <Hub Tapped="Hub_Tapped">
                <HubSection MinWidth="300" Header="ABC">
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox Header="Colors" PlaceholderText="Pick a color" Width="200" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                <x:String>Blue</x:String>
                                <x:String>Green</x:String>
                                <x:String>Red</x:String>
                            <x:String>Yellow</x:String>
                            </ComboBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                </HubSection>
                <HubSection MinWidth="300" Header="DEF"/>
            </Hub>
        </Grid>
     </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
```

It is recommended that you submit this unexpected behavior in Feedback Hub. You could find the Feedback Hub in the Start Menu.
Please select **Developer Platform**->**API Feedback** as the category when you submit your request.
The related team will check the request.

After you submit the request, please share your link, I will help you submit this feedback through internal channels.